# Tricky little encoding issue with PHP and emails

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I have an encoding issue when I email a welcome email with this character in it è

I open the email and get this: Ã¨

I have tried to set the encoding of the email to utf-8 and have checked the source of email to verify this.

I have tried using `htmlentities` `utf-encode` and `utf-decode` as well.

I have run out of idea. I don't understand why this is happening :S

---- EDIT -----

This is what I am using (at the moment, to try and encode it)

```
htmlentities($var, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', FALSE)
```

Comment: check to see what your file's encoding is, if it is in fact encoded as UTF-8, and also check if it's `with` or `without` [**BOM**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Byte Order Mark)

Comment: That looks like double-enconding to me. Make sure that all encodings match (file on filesystem, mail headers, recognized encoding in mail user agent)

Comment: Can you also post how you're performing encoding with your code?

Comment: *How* have you "set the encoding of the email to utf-8"? Show us a complete example email with headers as received by your email client.

Comment: "set the encoding" means I put this in: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: I would not encode the source text if it is already UTF-8 (i.e. something like `$content = "è";` and that you set your IDE to UTF-8 (or your text editor to save as UTF-8). Then make sure you add the headers in the php mail method: `$headers = "From: " . $from . " \r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $param = "-f" . $frommail;
  mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers,$param);` ... you might need to reformat the code above... or I should post it as an answer but you don't show any code, I can't be sure it's the way to go for you

Comment: Yep, looks like it is the headers in the function. Working on a big monolithic code base so the mail function was hidden away but yea thats it. Thanks!